# How to change variable value of angular 4 from jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

We are using ap-angular2-fullcalendar for event listing.
On callback(on click of event) function we want to update one of the variable value.

```
 this.calendarOptions = {
      height: 450,
      fixedWeekCount: false,
      defaultDate: today,
      editable: false,
      eventLimit: true,
      header: {
        left: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
      },
      events: [],
      eventClick: this.calEventOnClick
    };
```

calEventOnClick:

```
calEventOnClick(appObj, jsEvent, view){
   //Following are the angular properties which values we want to update
   this.sessionId = appObj.id;
   this.showAppoint = appObj;
   this.isAppointmentsBox = false;  // not working
   this.isAppointmentDetails =true; // not working
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using callbacks, keep in mind to always check the context; here you should use `bind(this)` to keep the context.

```
this.calendarOptions = {
  ...
  eventClick: this.calEventOnClick.bind(this)     // <----- bind context to callback here
};
```